# Do I need to use ESRI's Create Spatial Type functionality

Tags: arcgis-desktop, oracle-spatial, st-geometry

Does anyone know if I **need** to use ESRI's Create Spatial Type functionality when creating a field in a non ESRI / non geodatabase Oracle 11g database?

I have an older customer database in Oracle.  After enabling the datatype ST_GEOMETRY on the database via Oracle's Locator functionality, I added a column to an existing table and populated each row as a point with relevant x,y & ,srid values.

However, ArcGIS v10.2.1 does not even recognize the column as a valid datatype.  It labels it "unknown" in ArcCatalog and returns invalid data type when trying to build a query layer.

Would this indicate I need to use ESRI's [Create Spatial Type](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-spatial-type.htm) in order to get ArcGIS to recognize the dataype/column in this non-geodatabase?

If so, can someone explain *what* it is doing that simply enabling the datatype directly in ORACLE does not?

Any theories as to why ArcGIS will not recognize this ST_GEOMETRY datatype?!

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour], if you haven't already:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour  Could you copy/paste the text of the error you receive in your question?

Comment: Oracle has a ST_GEOMETRY type as well -- MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY; it's a wrapper around SDO_GEOMETRY.  I don't believe Esri supports MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY.

Comment: @Vince The [docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/DBMS_data_types_supported_in_ArcGIS/019v00000002000000/) say that SDO_GEOMETRY is supported, at least for reading data.

Comment: Certainly, `MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY` is supported (read-only in a Query Layer, and read/write through an enterprise geodatabase), but `MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY` is [not supported](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36688). The "ST_GEOMETRY" in that doc refers to `SDE.ST_GEOMETRY` (which is what Create Spatial Type installs).

Comment: What ended up being the correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is a name collision between differing implementations.  Esri developed the `SDE.ST_GEOMETRY` datatype long ago (at ArcSDE 8.0 for Oracle 8i), but Oracle started shipping an `MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY` type for [ISO compatibility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_sql_mm.htm) (I believe it was first released with Oracle 11gR1).

The "ST_GEOMETRY" you enabled through Locator is actually `MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY`, which is [not supported by ArcGIS](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36688).

You have two avenues for spatial type support in Oracle with ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.x:

1. Use `MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY` directly (`MDSYS.ST_GEOMETRY` is a wrapper around the SDO type)
2. Install `SDE.ST_GEOMETRY` via [Create Spatial Type](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-spatial-type.htm), and use that instead of the MDSYS wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll let you know how it works out...

Answer (score 2):

When adding new geometry columns in Oracle, be sure to update the `MDSYS.SDO_GEOM_METADATA` table.

> insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata (table_name, column_name, diminfo,
>   srid) values (your, values, go, here)